# Connect a router to multiple router/subnet - Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, router, subnet

I'm studying DNS Server. So I try this.

[image]

Here is the flow when I request ***abc.com*** webpage from *My PC*.

1. *My PC* (192.0.1.2) send DNS query to *Router0*. *Router0* then forwarding to *DNS Nameserver* (10.0.0.2).
2. *DNS Nameserver* return ***abc.com*** IP address to *my PC* through *Router0*.
3. *My PC* send request to ***abc.com*** IP address to *Router0*. *Router0* then forwarding to *ABC Server* (192.1.1.2 - forgot to write in the pic)
4. *ABC Server* return HTTP page for *my PC*.

Thing works fine. But I want to create more webpage, i.e: ***def.com***, ***igh.com***, so I need to create more server. **The problem is *Router0* has only 3 ports (interface).**

On my understanding, *Switch* component is use for connecting many device **in a same subnet**, i.e: *ABC Server* has many *Server* component so I can connect all of them to a *Switch*, then connect that *Switch* to *Router0*. **So it can't be used to solve my problem, which is connect different subnet.**

I have try to search Google: *How to connect a router to multiple router/subnet* but don't get the result.

I think maybe I haven't had enough *Computer Network* knowledge yet to think of solutions using other component than just *Switch*, *Router*.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use a switch with VLANs and trunk between the router and switch, using subinterfaces on the router. This is a large topic, but it is basic to configuring networks.

Comment: Are you sure you need a separate subnet for each server?

Comment: @RonTrunk For learning purpose ... :)

Comment: @RonMaupin You kinda DDoS my brain... XoX

Comment: Please use CIDR notation for all subnets in general. /24 is not a given.

Comment: See if [this question and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32059/vlans-cisco-packet-tracer) helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thing works fine. But I want to create more webpage, i.e: def.com, igh.com, so I need to create more server. The problem is Router0 has only 3 ports (interface).

You can either host all those web domains on one server or connect multiple servers using switches. A switch allows a router port to attach to a whole network of hosts and to provide gateway services to them.

A **simple (unmanaged) switch** connects all ports to a common L2 segment = broadcast domain = IP subnet. That way, all hosts can directly talk to each other which may not be desired in some scenarios.

Using a **managed switch**, you can group your hosts into VLANs that are separate on layer 2 (for enhanced security for instance). For them to communicate they need to use a router which is where you can control their traffic. If you use VLANs on the switch you can trunk them to the router and use VLAN subinterfaces to attach to each VLAN.

Alternatively, you could use a **layer-3 switch** and route all the VLANs together independently from the router. This is more efficient when there's a lot of inter-host traffic.

Comment: Can you draw a picture to illustrate? I'm kinda newbie zZz. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, I found something that seems the same to your idea, can you check this out? Thanks. https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/routing-between-vlans

Comment: Sorry, we can't go through that amount of detail here. This site is intended to answer rather concise questions, see the [tour]. It is not intended for general *how-to*. The link you posted is the latter and seems useful.